# Relocate element with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have in my HTML:

```
Get <span class="geo_currency">$</span>50 on your next order...
```

I'm already overwriting the currency based on geo location (works fine) BUT for a few currencies I need to relocate the currency so it comes AFTER the number, as in

```
50<span class="geo_currency">kr</span>
```

Pls note that:

-The HTML as shown above is strict; e.g. is always

```
<span class="geo_currency">$</span>someNumber
```

-the amount of digits in the number can vary

-there's always a space after the number (I guess that's what we need to look for?)

Thx a lot - any ideas?

Comment: It would be easier if you would wrap the price in a `span` element as well. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

I know this doesn't exactly answer your question, but maybe you can solve this particular issue with a pseudo element by changing your HTML just a tiny bit:

```
Get <span class="geo_currency" data-currency="euro">50</span> on your next order.
```

With LESS like this:

```
span.geo_currency {
    &[data-currency="euro"]:after {
        content: "€";
    }
    &[data-currency="dollar"]:before {
        content: "$";
    }
}
```

Or, for purists, this CSS:

```
span.geo_currency[data-currency="euro"]:after {
    content: "€";
}
span.geo_currency[data-currency="dollar"]:before {
    content: "$";
}
```

Comment: Good idea! (although I'd find a pure CSS example better).

Comment: How is this not "pure" CSS?

Comment: You said yourself you provided an example written in LESS. That's not CSS.

Comment: Fair enough, although LESS eventually becomes CSS. I just thought it made the answer more readable.

Comment: Why I didn't think of that...I go for the pure CSS approach anyway. Thx a lot!

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with a a regular expression: e.g.

**Swap KR50 to 50KR**

```
//assign the parent to make things a little readable
parent = $('span.geo_currency').parent();
//swap the span
parent.html(parent.html().replace(/(<span class="geo_currency">.*<\/span>)([\d\.\,]{1,20})/, '$2$1'));
```

**Swap 50KR to KR50**

```
//assign the parent to make things a little readable
parent = $('span.geo_currency').parent();
//swap the span
parent.html(parent.html().replace(/([\d\.\,]{1,20})(<span class="geo_currency">.*<\/span>)/, '$2$1'));
```

**Limitations**

- I'm assuming your HTML has a suitable parent otherwise scanning the DOM would be nasty.
- That your numbers are a floats, < 20 characters with only a dot or comma as separators.
- It won't be a sentence, with a full stop be a sentence e.g. With this you'll get KR50.

here is a working example : http://jsfiddle.net/fEksT/

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to go via JS to support browsers that don't like `:before` and `:after`, I've managed to work out a way to do it:

```
$(".geo_currency").each(function() {
    var indx = $(this).index();
    var textNode = $(this).parent().contents()[indx+2];
    var txt = textNode.textContent;
    var num = txt.match(/^[0-9]+/)[0];
    var newSpan = $("<span>").html(num).append($(this)).append(txt.substr(num.length));
    $(textNode).before(newSpan).remove();
    $(newSpan).get(0).outerHTML = $(newSpan).html();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sxpKc/)

Comment: Hi, thx for your work but I realize now jQuery might not be the best solution to handle this. The above CSS approach from n3rd is, for this task, a cleaner solution IMO. Thx anyway!